# Where I can get correction my sentences on English

Tags: grammar

I finding service where my english sentences correcting a native speakers. I used lang-8.com. But correction was rare. I find same service like it. Ore another where I get help. don't matter free or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about English language

Comment: www.italki.com offers free proofreading by native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm looking for a service where I can get my English sentences corrected by native speakers. I used lang-8.com, but corrections were rare. I am looking for some service like it, or another where I can get help. It doesn't matter if it is free or not".

Well, firstly this is a good site, although you may need to improve your English some more to get full benefit. Your question is off-topic according to the rules and I would suggest that just reading through the questions and answers posted here may help you.

Comment: I didn't know of this website, as I checked it, it had an interesting idea! Are there other good websites like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a good website, but you better should ask for rules or the correct grammar between two or more sentences rather than create lots of threads asking for a correction of a sentence or a text. Anyway, you will probably learn more if we explain to you how it works and why.

You're welcome to this website. We hope StackExchange will be useful to you.